# IntelliJ cannot read scheme when starting

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

I keep getting error messages when I start IntelliJ.  There are about 5 or 6 of them, all like the attached image, but each with a different color scheme named.  Is there a way for me to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Mac: open Finder and go to ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/colors and delete the conflicting color schema (Monokai.icls in your case), then open IntelliJ, the error message should not be shown up anymore.